# Parent child relationship Join tables in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

I have a requirement below.

[image: Table Structure containing Position details]

Now I have to get output like below

[image]

How can this be achieved ?
I have written the below SQL but parent_position_id is coming, not parent_position_code

```
select
hapf.position_code,
pphf.parent_position_id
from
hr_all_positions_f hapf, PER_POSITION_HIERARCHY_F pphf
where
hapf.position_id = pphf.position_id
```

Should I write a sub query? How should I proceed ?
This is Oracle SQL

Thanks,
Shivam

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `JOIN` again.

Comment: Can you please tell me how these joins would work ?

Comment: I got it, I used this SQL query as a table to join in another query. I think this is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noone ever said you could only join a table in once:

```
select
  chi.position_code,
  par.position_code as parent_position_code
from
  hr_all_positions_f hapf
  INNER JOIN PER_POSITION_HIERARCHY_F chi on hapf.position_id = chi.position_id
  INNER JOIN PER_POSITION_HIERARCHY_F par on hapf.parent_position_id = par.position_id
```

Bear it in mind; I see people coming to thinking all the time that they can only join a table once. If one table decodes a value in 3 different columns, then you sure can join that same table in 3 times... Imagine if it were an address table, and a Student had a HomeAddressId, WorkAddressId and StudyAddressId, and the Address table held all these addresses - you'd join the  addresses table to the Student table 3 times to get all the data..

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply, this is a easy way to do it than I was doing it.